# C++ getting only the middle part of data from an array

Tags: c++, string

I have an array like this:

```
string dates [5] = { "15-JAN-17", "15-JAN-17", "17-JAN-17", 
                  "04-FEB-17", "04-FEB-17" }; 

string startDate = "15-JAN-17";
string endDate   = "04-FEB-17";
```

Is there a way to get the data in between the start date and end date? What I need to get is this:

```
"15-JAN-17", "17-JAN-17", "04-FEB-17"
```

I plan to use a for loop to do the search, and I will put all the results into another array called chosenDates. How can I get this result and also since there will be duplicated dates, how can I ensure that the program starts taking from the first result and ends at the last result as provided by startDate and endDate?

EDIT: I should also mention that even if the array gets larger, the dates will always be sorted.

Comment: You mean get the data between two pointers of your array or get the data between two objects of your array which are equals to the mentioned strings ?

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: Is the type of `dates` really **`int`** `[5]`?

Comment: I mean to get the data between the mentioned strings. However since the dates might have duplicates, I need to get the data between the first "15-JAN-17" and the last "04-FEB-17".

Oh yes I screwed up, shall change the array to string xD

Comment: If the array is [sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) then [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) (and a call to [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sorts of operations you're planning on performing on these strings, I think it makes the most sense to define some new custom type to represent dates. The constructor would parse the date string into an explicit year, month, and day, and you could provide read access to each field. Once you've done that, you could overload the relational operators on your date type so that you can compare and order dates into ascending order.

Once you have something like that, you have a number of options about how to proceed. One approach would be to throw everything into a `std::set`, which automatically eliminated duplicates and maintains sorted order, which would let you execute range queries like this:

```
std::set<Date> dates = /* ... */
for (auto itr = dates.lower_bound(Date{"15-JAN-17"}),
     end = dates.upper_bound(Date{"04-FEB-17"});
    itr != end; ++itr) {
    // Use *itr
}
```

You could also stash everything in a `std::vector` use `std::unique` to remove duplicates, then use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` to select the range you'd like to work with.